# What is "skate ramp" in Chinese?

Tags: word-requests

What is "skate ramp" in Chinese? I can't seem to find this in any dictionaries, and most skate parks in Taiwan are called "Extreme Sports Training Park" or simply "Sports Park", so I don't really know where to start.

If there isn't an established name for a skate ramp in Chinese, how can I say it in Chinese in a way that is understandable?

Comment: iciba: 滑板坡道    ....

Comment: What is "iciba"?

Comment: searching web using "iciba" or 爱词霸 will provide a hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean half-pipe? 
That'd be 半管.

Vert ramp? 
U型池.

English is equally acceptable though, not a lot of Chinese terms.

The broadest term you'll get is (滑板, etc.)道具, or if you want to be slightly more specific you can say 木制道具.